# Wordpress AJAX call from outside theme [For a jQuery mobile/Phonegap app]

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm just playing around for the first time with both jQM and Phonegap. For starters I would like to load a few posts (custom post type - team members) from a Wordpress site and display them inside a list. Then upon tapping the list item, I would like it to transition to a view where the whole post is displayed.

I haven't even got to deploying it on the emulator, since it won't even work in the browser.

I thought I was going to be able to call jQuery's AJAX function the same way I run it inside a Wordpress theme, but it doesn't work...

This is what I've done so far:

- set up the phonegap + jQuery mobile combination
- set up the path to the wp admin-ajax file
- create the function and add ajax action inside my functions file
- call the AJAX function

  function getTeamMembers()
  {
      console.log( 'getting members');
      $.ajax({
          url: ajaxUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'action=get_team_members',
          success: function( response ) 
          {
              console.log( 'get em' );
              console.log( response );
          }
      });
  }

The function in functions.php just echoes a simple string and exits.

The response shows up red in the Firebug console, with a code 200 OK, and the response is empty. The 'got em' string does not show up at all, so I assume the request was not successful. Chrome wouldn't even run it because the AJAX call is to another server.

So basically what I'm asking is.. is there a way to somehow use the same ajax calls and retrieve data from a Wordpress page using the functions.php file from outside the theme ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

It was as easy as adding

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

to the beginning of the function that is called by AJAX.

Beautiful.